# mysql_query php не работает

Tags: php, mysql

Не работает отправка запроса. Хочу получить число строк, а потом в цикле фор обработать вывод элементов графы username

```
<html>
<? 
     echo '<title>govnokod // Каталог пользователей</title>';
     $db = mysqli_connect('aa','a','aa','a');
     if($db){
         echo'таблица успешно подключена';
     }
     $a = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users");
     if($a){
         echo 'запрос отправлен';
     }
     $b = mysql_fetch_row($a);
     if($b){
         echo 'ответ получен';
     }
     echo $b[0];
     for($i = 0; $i<8; $i = $i+1){
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `username` WHERE id=".$i);
        echo '<p align="center"><a href=" '.$result.' /">'.$i.'</a></p> ';
     }
      ?>
</html>
```

Comment: Не работает именно отправка запроса, или его получение? И какого из 2х?

Comment: id=".$i." " );  /////////////////

Answer (score 1):

Для подключения вы используете функцию `mysqli_connect` из расширения MySQL**i** (Improved), а для выполнения запроса — функцию `mysql_query` из устаревшего расширения MySQL (Original). Замените все функции на `mysqli_query` и `mysqli_fetch_row`, и в дальнейшем всегда используйте только новое расширение [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php).

Подробная информация в документации: [mysqli_query](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php), [mysqli_fetch_row](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php).

P.S. И не пишите реальные данные для подключения к вашей БД в вопросе, с точки зрения безопасности.

Comment: спасибо, помогло.